# How to pass a fixed string as argument in call-param-rule in Commons Digester?

Tags: xml, apache-commons-digester

I am trying to call a method and pass a String as an argument to that method when processing a particular tag for XML-to-Object transformation using Digester:

```
<pattern value="abc/xyz">
    <object-create-rule classname="com.test.XYZ"/>
    <call-method-rule methodname="setTypeName" paramcount="1" paramtypes="java.lang.String"/>
    <call-param-rule paramnumber="0"/>
</pattern>
```

This sets the typeName in XYZ to empty string, but I want to set it to some other fixed string (e.g. "test"). How do I specify this fixed string in call-method-rule or call-param-rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `object-param-rule` for this

Try

```
<pattern value="abc/xyz">
    <object-create-rule classname="com.test.XYZ"/>
    <call-method-rule methodname="setTypeName" paramcount="1" paramtypes="java.lang.String"/>
    <object-param-rule paramnumber="0" type="java.lang.String" value="test" />
</pattern>
```